# malformed Java Net URL

Tags: java, http, url

I am making a url like this

```
url = new URL("http","localhost",9080,"/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action");
```

instead of making the url:

```
http://localhost:9080/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action
```

its making the request to:

```
http://www.localhost.com/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action
```

Comment: Are you sure.? Try to print the contents of url because when i tried printing the content of url it is `http://localhost:9080/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action`

Comment: tried that, print the wrong url for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action");
```

Comment: If you would like to keep the version you are using, I think it would work if you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I actually made an error typing in the URL, when testing this I left out the // after http: so the call was getting made to http:localhost:9080/path/to/my/resource/myAction.action, soon as I put in // it reverted to www.localhost.com URL :S

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1 instead?